# Return in a for loop function

Tags: python

What's wrong with this?
Why is this always True no matter what I input?

```
def duplicates(s):
    for c in s:
        if s.count(c) > 1:
            
            return False
            
        else:
            return True

print(duplicates("god"))
print(duplicates("goo"))
print(duplicates("good"))
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? The first character is "g" and when you count the occurrences of "g" in your string `s`, it gives 1 and goes into the `else` loop and returns `True` as expected.

Comment: if-else condition checks both have return statements. so the loop never iterates after the first character check.

Comment: What are you really trying to do....each time character count is one and goes to else condition,then returning with true value

Comment: @SamkitJain "god" should be True since it doesn't contain a duplicate letter.The others should be False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop body never executes more than once, since no matter what, you are executing a return of either `True` or `False` on the very first iteration.

To fix it, only return `False` from within the loop.  Don't return `True` until after the loop exits:

```
def duplicates(s):
    for c in s:
        if s.count(c) > 1:
            return False

    return True
```

The function name is a little misleading, since it returns `True` if there are no duplicates and `False` if there are duplicates.

Comment: The loop body never executes more than once. Why? Do you mean the loop only counts the first letter?

Comment: @kile Exactly.  On the first iteration, it looks at the first letter.  If it's a duplicate, it immediately returns `False`.  Otherwise it immediately returns `True`.  Execution never makes it past the `if` statement.